# Initialize Mustache.js with RequireJS to have different delimiters/tags

Tags: javascript, requirejs, mustache

I was wondering if there was a way to initialize the Mustache.js library with RequireJS so that it uses different delimiters.

I have the following right now, but the `parseTags` aren't being passed along.

config.js:

```
requirejs.config(
    paths: {
        'mustache': '.../mustache.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'mustache': {
            'init': function(mustache) {
                return mustache.parseTags(['"[[", "]]"']);
            }
        }
    });
```

template.js

```
define(['mustache'], function(mustache) {
    mustache.render(template. {...});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how `shim`s work; you could instead call `mustache.parseTags` in your `main.js` (or whichever main file you have) which should update the Mustache singleton prior to any later calls to `render`.

Comment: We don't have a `main.js` file, is there a way to update the Mustache singleton using RequireJS?

Comment: You have to have SOME file that kicks off the rest of your scripts; do it there, even if it's just the module that renders the first template.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest using the [deps](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-deps) and [callback](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-callback) configuration variables to perform the configuration.

```
require.config({
  // ...
  deps: ['mustache'],
  callback: function (mustache) {
    // configure mustache here.
  }
});
```

But from the [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) page, I get the impression that the tag configuration is set inside the template itself. (I'm not a mustache expert, so if there is a way, please use the above configuration.)

Also, I didn't find a reference to the `parseTags` function, but assuming the init() method mentioned in your question is correct, then you could create your own custom_mustache.js module that returns that reference.

```
// custom_mustache.js
define(['mustache'], function (mustache) {
    return mustache.parseTags(['"[[", "]]"']);
})
```